# How do I get my Azure DevOps Pipeline build to fail when my linting script returns an error?

Tags: azure, azure-devops, pipeline, devops, azure-pipelines

I am using the Azure Pipelines GitHub add-on to ensure that pull requests pass my linting. However, I have just made a test pull request which fails my linting, but the Azure Pipeline succeeds.

Here is my `azure-pipelines.yml`

```
# Node.js with React
# Build a Node.js project that uses React.
# Add steps that analyze code, save build artifacts, deploy, and more:
# https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/devops/pipelines/languages/javascript

trigger:
- master

pool:
  vmImage: 'Ubuntu-16.04'

steps:
- task: NodeTool@0
  inputs:
    versionSpec: '8.x'
  displayName: 'Install Node.js'

- script: |
    npm install
    npm run lint # Mapped to `eslint src` in package.json
    npm run slint # `stylelint src` in package.json
    npm run build
  displayName: 'npm install and build'
```

And here is (part of) the output on a branch which I know fails on `npm run lint`

```
> geograph-me@0.1.0 lint /home/vsts/work/1/s
> eslint src


/home/vsts/work/1/s/src/js/components/CountryInput.js
  26:45  error  'onSubmit' is missing in props validation  react/prop-types
  27:71  error  'onSubmit' is missing in props validation  react/prop-types

✖ 2 problems (2 errors, 0 warnings)

npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! geograph-me@0.1.0 lint: `eslint src`
npm ERR! Exit status 1 # Exit status 1, yet the build succeeds?
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the geograph-me@0.1.0 lint script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/vsts/.npm/_logs/2019-03-16T05_30_52_226Z-debug.log

> geograph-me@0.1.0 slint /home/vsts/work/1/s
> stylelint src


> geograph-me@0.1.0 build /home/vsts/work/1/s
> react-scripts build

Creating an optimized production build...
Compiled successfully.

# Truncated...
```

As you can see, linter runs nicely and catches my intentional error (I removed a prop type validation), and exits with code 1.

However the build just carries on its merry way.

What do I need to do to make such a linting error stop my build in its tracks and not return success?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Have you figured out a way to report these lint errors/warnings in the summary tab of the pipeline?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

this means your script "swallows" the exit code and exits normally. you need to add a check to your script that would catch the exit code of your `npm run lint` and exit with the same exit code, something like:

```
- script: |
    npm install
    npm run lint # Mapped to `eslint src` in package.json
    if [ $? -ne 0 ]; then
        exit 1
    fi
    npm run slint # `stylelint src` in package.json
    npm run build
```

Comment: Can you please provide a link that can explain the syntax around your following code? `if [ $? -ne 0 ]; then`.

Comment: it's explained in the answer. $? - returns last exit code

Comment: Is that azure-pipelines syntax ($?)? Where does it come from, npm? I'd like to do further reading on this.

Comment: @Zac https://askubuntu.com/questions/324423/how-to-access-the-last-return-value-in-bash

Comment: Does anybody know a way to report these errors/warnings to the summary tab of the pipeline? (or somewhere else for that matter, other than drilling down)

Answer (score 7):

You could also use an npm task. The default is to fail the build when there is an error. I had the same problem and the below worked for me:

```
- task: Npm@1
  displayName: 'Lint'
  inputs:
    command: 'custom'
    customCommand: 'run lint'
```

From the documentation for [tasks](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/tasks?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml):

```
- task: string  # reference to a task and version, e.g. "VSBuild@1"
  condition: expression     # see below
  continueOnError: boolean  # 'true' if future steps should run even if this step fails; defaults to 'false'
  enabled: boolean          # whether or not to run this step; defaults to 'true'
  timeoutInMinutes: number  # how long to wait before timing out the task
```

Answer (score 2):

Neither approach above worked for my specific scenario (windows build agent, wanted to run a custom linting script, didn't want to use a script in package.json)

If you just throw an error from a node script, the pipeline treats it as a failed step.

pipelines yml:

```
  - script: 'node lint-my-stuff'
    displayName: 'Lint my stuff'
```

lint-my-stuff.js

```
// run eslint, custom checks, whatever

if (/* conditions aren't met */)
  throw new Error('Lint step failed')

console.log('Lint passed')
```